# Unable to select Continue button using XPath, CSS Selector or Link Text

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

Attempting to create a regression test using Python for Checkout Process.  Getting error when attempting to click Continue button.  Have tried using Find_Element with Xpath, CSS Selector and Link Text.

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())

username = 'bmendenhall@sans.org'
password = 'Lloydcole2!'
welcome = 'Welcome'
firstname = 'Bruce'
lastname = 'Parker'
phone = '555-555-5555'
email = 'bmendenhall+regression@sans.org'

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

driver.get('https://www.sans.org/')
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a[aria-label='Log In']").click()
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[id='username']").send_keys(username)
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[id='password']").send_keys(password)
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[id='regularsubmit']").click()
time.sleep(3)
driver.get('https://www.sans.org/')

trainandcert = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "li[aria-label='Train and Certify']")))
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(trainandcert).perform()

courses = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "li[aria-label='Courses']")))
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(courses).click().perform()

driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a[aria-label='Pricing & Training Options']").click()
driver.get('https://www.sans.org/cyber-security-courses/hacker-techniques-incident-handling/#training-and-pricing')

time.sleep(3)

# Need to add item to cart
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a[class='course-run-section-button button button--small button--light button--primary']").click()

time.sleep(3)
# Add on Cart
# button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[6]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div/c-rckt-cart/div/lightning-layout/slot/lightning-layout-item[2]/slot/c-rckt-order-summary/div/div/div/lightning-button/button")
# driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", button)
time.sleep(30)

driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//button[@title='proceed to checkout']").click()

time.sleep(10)

driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[@id='input-72']").clear()
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[@id='input-72']").send_keys(firstname)
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[@id='input-74']").clear()
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[@id='input-74']").send_keys(lastname)
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[@id='input-80']").clear()
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[@id='input-80']").send_keys(phone)
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[@id='input-84']").clear()
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[@id='input-84']").send_keys(email)
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[@id='input-86']").clear()
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[@id='input-86']").send_keys(email)

#Attempt to Click Continue via XPath
# driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[@title='continue']").click()

#Attmpt to Click Continue via CSS Selector
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button[title='continue']").click()

#Attmpt to Click Continue by button Name
# driver.find_element(By.LINK_TEXT, "Continue").click()

time.sleep(30)

driver.close()
```

Attempting to proceed through the checkout process.  Getting stuck on the Attendee Info page. Unable to click the Continue button

Error Message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/BMendenhall/Desktop/Projects/sans-domain-testing/XTAL-403.py", line 69, in <module>
    driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button[title='continue']").click()
  File "/Library/Python/3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 857, in find_element
    return self.execute(Command.FIND_ELEMENT, {
  File "/Library/Python/3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 435, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/Library/Python/3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 247, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"button[title='continue']"}
  (Session info: chrome=107.0.5304.87)
```

Comment: If you're getting an error, please post the full traceback.

Comment: Added Error Messaged to the original post.  Thanks!

Comment: It seems self-explanatory, the button you're trying to click on doesn't exist.

Comment: I hope that isn't your real password.

Comment: That's the frustrating part.  the Continue button is there.  I have pulled the CSS Selector as I have on other pages without issue.  But I am still getting the error.

It is a test account.  Order don't actually go through.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure it's `title='continue'` rather than `id='continue'` like the other inputs? Also, check the case, it might be `Continue`.